# Snapper Exclusions in `/home` (btrfs)

Tags: btrfs, home, snapper

Is there a standard approach, when using [snapper](http://snapper.io/) on btrfs, to exclude directories under users' home folders? Say... `~/.cache/yay` on Arch. Or possibly even `~/.cache` as a whole.

Of course, I know the SOP is to create a subvolume any time you want a folder's contents excluded from a snapshot of a subvolume higher in the mounted folder hierarchy. But that means making a subvolume for each excluded folder under `~/` each time a user is added. Which is, in addition to getting messy to maintain, quite a few extra steps on top of normal user creation.

I suppose I could create wrapper scripts for `useradd` and `userdel` and toss them in `/usr/local/sbin` so they take priority. But I thought I'd see if there isn't a more elegant approach.

#### Context

It's not critical. The only system I currently have snapper deployed on is a home gateway and it's unlikely to ever have more than one non-root user. But it would be nice to know for the future.

**subvolumes (excluding existing snapshots):**

```
$ sudo btrfs subvolume list /
ID 258 gen 33625 top level 5 path home
ID 262 gen 33553 top level 5 path opt
ID 264 gen 33555 top level 5 path var-www
ID 266 gen 33630 top level 5 path arch
ID 267 gen 33631 top level 5 path var-log
ID 268 gen 33566 top level 5 path pacman-cache
ID 270 gen 45 top level 266 path var/lib/portables
ID 271 gen 46 top level 266 path var/lib/machines
ID 274 gen 33566 top level 266 path .snapshots
ID 276 gen 33556 top level 258 path home/.snapshots
ID 278 gen 33556 top level 262 path opt/.snapshots
ID 279 gen 33556 top level 264 path var-www/.snapshots
```

**/etc/fstab:**

```
# /dev/sda6 LABEL=system
UUID=18f47506-31c6-4d22-939d-684ace61301f / btrfs rw,noatime,compress=zstd:3,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=266,subvol=/arch,subvol=arch 0 0

# /dev/sda6 LABEL=system
UUID=18f47506-31c6-4d22-939d-684ace61301f /.snapshots btrfs rw,nodev,noexec,noatime,compress=zstd:3,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=274,subvol=/arch/.snapshots,subvol=arch/.snapshots 0 0

# /dev/sda1
UUID=27d5943f-e74d-480f-be46-a370c5b1f37f /boot ext4 rw,noatime,nodev,nosuid,noexec 0 2

# /dev/sda6 LABEL=system
UUID=18f47506-31c6-4d22-939d-684ace61301f /home btrfs rw,noatime,nodev,compress=zstd:3,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=258,subvol=/home,subvol=home 0 0

# /dev/sda6 LABEL=system
UUID=18f47506-31c6-4d22-939d-684ace61301f /home/.snapshots btrfs rw,nodev,noexec,noatime,compress=zstd:3,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=276,subvol=/home/.snapshots,subvol=home/.snapshots 0 0

# /dev/sda6 LABEL=system
UUID=18f47506-31c6-4d22-939d-684ace61301f /opt btrfs rw,noatime,nodev,nosuid,compress=zstd:3,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=262,subvol=/opt,subvol=opt 0 0

# /dev/sda6 LABEL=system
UUID=18f47506-31c6-4d22-939d-684ace61301f /opt/.snapshots btrfs rw,nodev,noexec,noatime,compress=zstd:3,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=278,subvol=/opt/.snapshots,subvol=opt/.snapshots 0 0

# /dev/sda6 LABEL=system
UUID=18f47506-31c6-4d22-939d-684ace61301f /var/log btrfs rw,noatime,nodev,nosuid,noexec,compress=zstd:3,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=267,subvol=/var-log,subvol=var-log 0 0

# /dev/sda6 LABEL=system
UUID=18f47506-31c6-4d22-939d-684ace61301f /var/www btrfs rw,noatime,nodev,nosuid,noexec,compress=zstd:3,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=264,subvol=/var-www,subvol=var-www 0 0

# /dev/sda6 LABEL=system
UUID=18f47506-31c6-4d22-939d-684ace61301f /var/www/.snapshots btrfs rw,nodev,noexec,noatime,compress=zstd:3,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=279,subvol=/var-www/.snapshots,subvol=var-www/.snapshots 0 0

# /dev/sda6 LABEL=system
UUID=18f47506-31c6-4d22-939d-684ace61301f /var/cache/pacman/pkg btrfs rw,noatime,nodev,nosuid,noexec,compress=zstd:3,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=268,subvol=/pacman-cache,subvol=pacman-cache 0 0

# /dev/sda5
UUID=5415bf33-0a89-4a36-a224-27dbb4c43977 none swap defaults 0 0
```

Comment: when a subvolume is mounted, nested subvolumes are mounted as well, automatically, no need to be in fstab

Comment: @Andre While true, my understanding is that such would create problems when rolling back a snapper snapshot. The solution for which is to explicitly mount subvolumes where they belong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The granularity of snapper (with BTRFS) is the BTRFS snapshot. Given the boundary of snapshots is the BTRFS subvolume, no you cannot configure snapper to exclude directories/folders. snapper simply doesn't have any control over this.

On my system I do exactly as you mentioned; Create subvolumes for the directories I don't want to snapshot.

To set up this approach during the creation of user accounts, you can create a skelleton (skell) directory which contains a shell script which upon user login creates the necessary subvolumes, if they don't already exist; With BTRFS, non-root users can create subvolumes (but cannot delete them).

Said skelleton directory will be copied to the user's home directory when using `useradd`. Then, when the user first logs in the subvolumes for, say .cache, would be created. No need for wrapper scripts. See `man useradd`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize subvolumes could be created by non-root users. That *does* simplify things. TY!

Comment: I also realize just now that subvols can be created by non-root user. In addition, I also found that although non-root user can not delete the subvol using `btrfs subvol delete`, but the user is allowed to simply do `rmdir subvol` or `rm -r subvol`, which can effectively delete the subvol.